# SQL Stored Procedure Unknown Where Clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to write an SQL stored proc, where it isn't known until run time how many parameters are to be included in the where clause and which columns those target?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing SQL stored procedure entirety of WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085756/passing-sql-stored-procedure-entirety-of-where-clause)

Comment: You have to be a little more specific I think.  It IS possible (to a degree) to use OR and AND logic with grouping, or alternately null-value handling if your DB supports it (i.e. NVL() function) to search by a parameter if it has a value but otherwise ignore it.  This can get messy fast, and can affect performance too.  Generally the best option if you're careful is dynamic SQL, where you build the query as a string and execute it.  The usual caveats regarding SQL injection apply.

Answer (score 3):

You could build dynamic sql in the stored proc and then execute it.  I wouldn't recommend doing this, but it is an option.

If you do go this route, make sure you give [this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) a thorough read.

UPDATE:

Disclaimer - the article above is specific to SQL Server.  Some of it may still apply though (I don't know enough about Oracle to say one way or the other).

I would recommend taking a look at [this article](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm) for Oracle specific information on Dynamic SQL.

Comment: Just be very sure you do not open yourself up to SQL Injection vulnerabilities when doing this. Sanitize anything sent to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many columns that you can search by, then building a dynamic sql statement would be easier but... you have to worry about sql injection

OR

if you know the columns that will be searched, create an optional parameter for each of those columns and assign a default value of null to them

Edit: added sample in sql server but easily portable to oracle

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test
(
    @col1   varchar(50) = null,
    @col2   int = null,
    @col3   datetime = null
)
AS

    SELECT  col1, col2, col3
    FROM    someTable
    WHERE   (@col1 IS NULL OR col1 = @col1)
    AND     (@col2 IS NULL OR col2 = @col2)
    AND     (@col3 IS NULL OR col3 = @col3)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I do know the columns that will be searched, but I don't know how many parameters for each column.  For example for col1, there may be 2 where parameters.  Is this possible?  Thanks again.

Comment: It is possible but becomes more difficult. The way we tackled it was to determine which parameters could have potential multiple values and passed in a csv string. We had a user defined function which parsed the csv and returned a table that we then did a left join on. In our case though, it was only one parameter that accepted multiple values so it was easier to maintain